# ZOOMOOZ: Is there a way to bind window resize to zoomTarget?

Tags: resize, window, bind, zoomooz

When using the zoomooz.js script, to enable zooming on a target, we simply add the zoomTarget class:

Ex. `<div id="container" class="zoomTarget"></div>`

However, zoom will only occur when "container" is clicked. Is there a way to automatically zoom to the target "container" once the browser window is resized?

Something like `$(window).resize(function(){ $("#container").zoomTarget(); });` perhaps?

Comment: I think I might have found out the answer to this question myself. instead of zoomTarget, I used zoomTo and bound it $(window).resize().